# It is possible to hide some equations and then go revealing one by one gradually in the beamer environment?

Tags: beamer, animations

I have this frame code:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Problem}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:problem}
    \begin{aligned}
        \begin{cases}
            &   \frac{dE}{dt} = \phi(p) (1-\frac{E}{C(t)}) F_{2} - \sigma_{A}(p)E - \mu_{E}(p)E - c_{E}(t)E\\

            \\& \frac{dA}{dt} = \sigma_{A}(p)E - \gamma(p)A - \mu_{A}(p)A - c_{A}(t)A\\

            \\& \frac{dF_{1}}{dt} = \gamma(p)A - \beta(p)F_{1} - \mu_{F_{1}}(p)F_{1} - c_{F_{1}}(t)F_{1}   \\

            \\& \frac{dF_{2}}{dt} = \beta(p)F_{1} - \mu_{F_{2}}(p)F_{2} - c_{F_{2}}(t)F_{2}  \\
        \end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
```

I want to know if it is possible to show the four equations in the first frame and then go revealing the second equation changing the color of the parameters that are common to both equations. For example:

The first frame

[image: The first frame]

The second frame

[image: The second frame]

The third frame and so on...

[image: The third frame]

I tried to use the \pause command but it seems that this one is not acceptable for math, only for text. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In the future, please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the overlay specification `\visible`, like this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Problem}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:problem}
    \begin{aligned}
        \begin{cases}
            \visible<1->{%
            &   \frac{dE}{dt} = \phi(p) (1-\frac{E}{C(t)}) F_{2} - \alert<2-3>{\sigma_{A}(p)E} - \mu_{E}(p)E - c_{E}(t)E\\
            }
            \visible<1,3->{%
            \\& \frac{dA}{dt} = \alert<3>{\sigma_{A}(p)E} - \gamma(p)A - \mu_{A}(p)A - c_{A}(t)A\\
            }
            \visible<1,4->{%
            \\& \frac{dF_{1}}{dt} = \gamma(p)A - \alert<4-5>{\beta(p)F_{1}} - \mu_{F_{1}}(p)F_{1} - c_{F_{1}}(t)F_{1}   \\
            }
            \visible<1,5->{%
            \\& \frac{dF_{2}}{dt} = \alert<5>{\beta(p)F_{1}} - \mu_{F_{2}}(p)F_{2} - c_{F_{2}}(t)F_{2}  \\
            }
        \end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are others too (`\only`, `\onslide`, `\uncover`, etc.) See the beamer documentation for details.